# How does "Iterator::collect" make transformation?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    use std::iter::Filter;
    use std::vec::IntoIter;
    let it: IntoIter<i32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].into_iter();
    let it2: Filter<IntoIter<i32>, _> = it.filter(|e| e % 2 == 0);
    let coll: Vec<i32> = it2.collect();

    println!("{:?}", coll);
}
```

If the program above is correct, [`t2.collect()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Filter.html#method.collect) will trigger a function call of `FromIterator::from_iter()`, which will in turn call `Vec<T>::from_iter()`.

It is well known that `filter` is *lazy*, and the transformation will take in effect when `collect` or `next` is being called.

But, follow the calling chain in the standard library, that is, `Iterator::collect --> FromIterator::from_iter() --> Vec<T>::from_iter()`. I haven't see the closure `|e| e % 2 == 0` (namely Filter's `predicate` field) being present and being called. This makes no sense since `predicate` should have been called before the vector being returned, so that the closure we supplied to `Filter` would filter the elements(**transformation** from [1,2,3,4,5] to [2,4]). Is my inference correct? If so, when is it called?

Comment: The iterator is passed to `from_iter()`. The closure is part of that iterator. How do you suspect that function gets values from the iterator?

Comment: `filter` returns a `Filter` struct. See the [`impl Iterator for Filter`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9a19e7604436056fafe10dffc7214fc6adb88400/library/core/src/iter/adapters/filter.rs#L48) block where `self.predicate` is used in several places.

Comment: @JohnKugelman It seems only `next`, `size_hint`, `count`, `try_fold`, `fold` are implemented by `Filter`, the others use `Iterator` 's default implementation, `collect` is the one of the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is mostly correct. However, `Vec<T>::from_iter()` is not being passed the iterator `it`. It's being passed the iterator `it2`, which as your code correctly points out is a [`std::iterator::Filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Filter.html). Now that type has a private implementation, which means you shouldn't rely upon how it's implemented, but for the sake of learning, we can dig into the Rust [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/filter.rs.html#15) and see what it really looks like on the inside.

```
pub struct Filter<I, P> {
    // Used for `SplitWhitespace` and `SplitAsciiWhitespace` `as_str` methods
    pub(crate) iter: I,
    predicate: P,
}
impl<I, P> Filter<I, P> {
    pub(in crate::iter) fn new(iter: I, predicate: P) -> Filter<I, P> {
        Filter { iter, predicate }
    }
}
```

So the `Filter` iterator stores the input iterator (which is actually your vector iterator) and the predicate function (a closure in your case).

Meanwhile, the [`Iterator` implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/filter.rs.html#47) for this type looks like this

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<I: Iterator, P> Iterator for Filter<I, P>
where
    P: FnMut(&I::Item) -> bool,
{
    type Item = I::Item;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        self.iter.find(&mut self.predicate)
    }

    // ... Other optimizations omitted for brevity ...

}
```

That is, when `collect` (or, more precisely, `from_iter`) asks the filter iterator for its next element, then the filter iterator *in turn* calls `find` on the original vector iterator, looking for not the first element of your vector but the first element that *satisfies some predicate*.

[`find`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.find) is also guaranteed to advance the input iterator to the position just after the first match, which means it can safely be called repeatedly (on the same iterator) to get every match.

---

**Edit:** In response to your comment wanting to know where `next` is invoked, we can trace the call stack for `from_iter` ourselves. You've already noticed that `collect` calls `from_iter`, in our case [`Vec::from_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2754). That method, in turn, does this

> ```
> <Self as SpecFromIter<T, I::IntoIter>>::from_iter(iter.into_iter())
> ```

[`SpecFromIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/spec_from_iter.rs.html#32) is a private trait that does some special-casing to make collecting vectors into other vectors faster. But the general, default case invokes [`SpecFromIterNested`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/spec_from_iter_nested.rs.html#20).

That trait, in turn, has two implementations. The first is for types that implement [`TrustedLen`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.TrustedLen.html). These are types whose `size_hint` method is contractually guaranteed to be accurate (rather than merely an optimization hint that can have an error margin). In that case, we end up doing [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/spec_extend.rs.html#40): (Comments are from the original source, they are not my additions)

> ```
> iterator.for_each(move |element| {
>   ptr::write(ptr, element);
>   ptr = ptr.add(1);
>   // Since the loop executes user code which can panic we have to bump the pointer
>   // after each step.
>   // NB can't overflow since we would have had to alloc the address space
>   local_len.increment_len(1);
> });
> ```

And [`for_each`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each) is, of course, an `Iterator` method that calls `next` until exhaustion and invokes a function for each element.

In the second case, where `TrustedLen` is not implemented, we call [`Vec::extend_desugared`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec/mod.rs.html#2849), which directly invokes `next` in a `while` loop until exhaustion.

So in either case, `next` gets called on the underlying iterator.

Of course, these are all implementation details. The only thing we really know for sure is that `from_iter` will build a collection based on an iterator. The fact that it uses this *particular* sequence of method calls may change in the future.

Comment: *"That is, when collect asks the filter iterator for its next element in turn calls find on the original vector iterator..."* -- In fact, that's my assumption as well at the first place, that is, `collect` will somehow calls `next` eventually(maybe `find` will be called as well), but since I cannot find the evidence for it, I would rather treat it as a hypothesis.

Comment: @absuu Good point. I've edited my answer to include a more detailed call tree.

Comment: Much appreciate your thorough and comprehensive analysis! That means a lot, thanks!